# How to correctly rewrite URLs?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I am a real noob in IIS URL rewrite module.

I want to rewrite all requests of

```
127.0.0.1/Content/[anything may come here]
```

to

```
127.0.0.1:7078/Content/[anything may come here]
```

I am very bad in regular expressions and I do not know how to do this

I tried using the wildcard feature in URL Rewrite module and did this:

Requested URL matches the pattern using wildcards

```
127.0.0.1/Scripts/*
```

then rewrite to

```
127.0.0.1:7078/Scripts/*
```

(Action Type is Rewrite)

I am attached a screenshot. I am not sure I am doing this the right way, because it is not working.

[image]

Comment: What regex did you try ?

Comment: I did not try any regex because I do not know it. I am having difficulty following the tutorials online.

Answer (score 0):

**1/** You don't need the host part in the Match URL Pattern : `/Scripts/*` should work.

**2/** If you want to match the wildcard in the Match URL Pattern to the Rewrite URL, you'll have to use something like `{R:0}` in the Rewrite URL. For example `127.0.0.1:7078/Scripts/{R:0}`.

**3/** I'm not sure you can rewrite to a different port. If rewrites does not work, try Redirect as Action Type instead.

If you want to hide port `7078`, you might need to use Application Request Routing (Reverse Proxy).

*Sources : http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module & http://forums.iis.net/t/1165389.aspx?URL+Rewrite+to+specific+port*